# Isomorphic finite fields of a skew field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-fields, division-rings

Let $D$ be a skew field and $F$ and $E$ be isomorphic finite subfields of $D$, is it true that $F=E$?

Comment: Note that if $D$ is finite or is commutative the claim is true.

Comment: The skew field of quaternions contains uncountably many subfields isomorphic to the complexes. The space of such subfields is naturally homeomorphic to the real projective plane P^2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not true. Suppose that $D$ is a skew field containing a finite field $F$ and $F$ is not contained in the center of $D$. Take $d \in D$ which does not commute with $F$. If $dFd^{-1}$ is distinct from $F$, then it is a subfield of $D$ isomorphic to $F$, and we're done. Otherwise, we have that $dFd^{-1} = F$, which means that conjugation by $d$ acts as a non-trivial automorphism of $F$.

Let $f \in F$ be a generator of the multiplicative group and then $dfd^{-1} = f^n$, where $f^n \neq f$. Now consider $(1+d)F(1+d)^{-1}$, which will also be a subfield of $D$. Assume for contradiction that $(1+d)F(1+d)^{-1} = F$. Then, that means $(1+d)f(1+d)^{-1} = f^m$ for some $m$. Rearranging, we get:
$$f^m + f^m d = f + df = f + f^nd$$
and so:
$$f-f^m = (f^m-f^n)d$$
If $f^n \neq f^m$, then $d$ is an element of $F$, which is a contradiction. On the other hand, if $f^n = f^m$, then $f = f^m$, and so $f = f^n$, which is also a contradiction. So we conclude that $(1+d)F(1+d)^{-1}$ is a subfield of $D$ isomorphic to $F$ but not equal to it.

It only remains to show that there actually is division ring $D$ with a finite subfield not contained in the center. The example I know of is to take the skew polynomial ring $\mathbb F_{p^k}[x; F]$ where $k \geq 2$ and $x$ acts by Frobenius, meaning that $x f = f^p x$ for $f \in \mathbb F_{p^k}$. Then, $\mathbb F_{p^k}[x; F]$ satisfies the Ore condition, so that it can be extended to a division ring. This gives example for $F$ isomorphic to any finite field other than a prime field, which is always unique.

Now you could ask whether any two finite subfields of a division ring which are isomorphic are always *conjugate*, and that I don't know.

Comment: I was wondering about this last question—it would be something like a [Witt's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem)-flavoured generalisation of [Skolem–Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem): can the isomorphism of $F$ with $E$, viewed as a non-inclusion embedding of $F$ in $D$, be extended to an automorphism of $D$?

Comment: Note that by Cartan-Brauer-Hua Theorem if $F$ is normal in $D$, then $F$ is contained in the center of $D$.

Comment: @AlborzAzarang, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464300/isomorphic-finite-fields-of-a-skew-field#comment1205834_464311), isn't that just what this answer is saying?

Answer (score 4):

The following answer is nearly identical to [@DustinCartwright's](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464311), which I saw after posting had been posted a few minutes earlier.  I only construct a specific division algebra with a non-central finite subfield differently.

No.  Let $\theta$ be a non-square in $\mathbb F_3$, put $k = \mathbb F_3(X)$ (i.e., rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb F_3$), and consider the quaternion algebra $D \mathrel{:=} (\theta, X)_k$ (in the [usual notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra#Structure)), so that there are elements $i, j \in D$ with $i^2 = \theta$, $j^2 = X$, and $i j = -j i$.  Then $D$ is a division algebra because the quadratic form $(a, b, c, d) \mapsto a^2 - b^2\theta - c^2 X - d^2\theta X$ on $k^4$ does not non-trivially represent $0$.

We have that $D$ contains a finite field $F \mathrel{:=} \mathbb F_3(i)$ with 9 elements.  One computes directly that the centralizer $C_D(F)$ equals $k[i] = F(X)$.  Since $N_{D^\times}(F)$ contains $j \notin C_{D^\times}(F)$, and since $N_{D^\times}(F)/C_{D^\times}(F)$ injects into the order-$2$ group $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb F_3)$, we have that $N_{D^\times}(F)$ equals $\langle j\rangle\cdot k[i]^\times$, which is a proper subgroup of $D^\times$.  For any element $g$ of $D^\times \setminus \langle j\rangle\cdot k[i]^\times$, we have that $E \mathrel{:=} g F g^{-1}$ is a subfield of $D$ that is isomorphic, but not equal, to $F$.

Comment: You might say explicitly that you provide a quaternion algebra over $k=\mathbf{F}_3(X)$ — how do you see that it's not split? By the way, the only non-square in $\mathbf{F}_3$ is $-1$.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464300/isomorphic-finite-fields-of-a-skew-field/464312#comment1205838_464312), non-splitness comes from the fact that $(a, b, c, d) \mapsto a^2 - \theta b^2 - X c^2 - \theta X d^2$ does not non-trivially represent $0$ on $\mathbb F_3(X)$, as can be seen by clearing denominators, looking at leading coefficients, and remembering that $(a, b) \mapsto a^2 - \theta b^2$ does not non-trivially represent $0$ on $\mathbb F_3$.  Other than that, I'm not sure what you mean that I should say explicitly—what should I change or add?

Comment: $(\theta,X)_k$ is by definition a quaternion algebra (and not "by definition" a division algebra), so once defined, it is worth saying that it is indeed a division algebra (with the argument of your previous comment).

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464300/isomorphic-finite-fields-of-a-skew-field/464312#comment1205847_464312), ah, I see.  I appreciate the suggestion.  I have edited accordingly.